# Java Backgroundworker: Scope of Widget to be updated unclear

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, backgroundworker

I am trying to understand the mechanism of `org.jdesktop.swingx.BackgroundWorker`. Their [javadoc](http://swinglabs.org/hudson/job/SwingX-WS%20Continuous%20Build/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/BackgroundWorker.html) presents following example:

```
final JLabel label;
class MeaningOfLifeFinder implements BackgroundListener {
    public void doInBackground(BackgroundEvent evt) {
        String meaningOfLife = findTheMeaningOfLife();
        evt.getWorker().publish(meaningOfLife);
    }

    public void process(BackgroundEvent evt) {
        label.setText("" + evt.getData());
    }

    public void done(BackgroundEvent evt) {}
    public void started(BackgroundEvent evt) {}
}

(new MeaningOfLifeFinder()).execute();
```

Apart from the fact that I doubt the result will ever get published, I wonder how `label` is passed to the process method, where it is being updated. I thought its scope was limited to the outside of the BackgroudListener implementation. Quite confused I am ... any answers for me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This snippet is obviously out of date and incorrect; in addition, you have to put it back into some context (I guess `MeaningOfLifeFinder` is defined inside another class).

It won't compile because `BackgroundListener` doesn't exist (should be `BackgroundWorker`) and is a class not an interface, hence `implements` is incorrect here.

I think the snippet should read like:

```
class Something {
   final JLabel label;

   Something() {
       // Instantiate label here
   }

   class MeaningOfLifeFinder implements BackgroundWorker {
       public void doInBackground(BackgroundEvent evt) {
           String meaningOfLife = findTheMeaningOfLife();
           evt.getWorker().publish(meaningOfLife);
       }

       public void process(BackgroundEvent evt) {
           label.setText("" + evt.getData());
       }

       public void done(BackgroundEvent evt) {}
       public void started(BackgroundEvent evt) {}
   }

   void someAction() {
       (new MeaningOfLifeFinder()).execute();
   }
}
```

This should work better. In this case, you immediately see how the instance of `MeaningOfLifeFinder` will be able to access label (since it can access any member of its embedding class).

You just have to make sure that `someAction()` gets called somehow (eg from a user action).

Comment: Ah thanks ... your answer makes me becoming more confident in myself!

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with [`BackgroundWorker`](http://swinglabs.org/hudson/job/SwingX-WS%20Continuous%20Build/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/BackgroundWorker.html), but it "is built upon [`SwingWorker`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)." Absent setting an `ExecutorService`, `BackgroundWorker` defaults to [`SwingWorker`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), which may be a more accessible model for study. Compare the "two threads involved in the life cycle of a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://swinglabs.org/hudson/job/SwingX-WS%20Continuous%20Build/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/BackgroundWorker.html)" with "[`SwingWorker`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) which can operate with three."